# Failed to fetch Clickwrap details. Status code: 401 and error 500 "an error has occurred"

Tags: docusignapi

is the url I use correct?

when i do requests.post I get error 500 and when i do requests.get I get error 401.

This is the code I used. and its failing at the requests.get

```
clickwrap_id = 'something'
headers = { 
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
clickwrap_url = f'https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/v1/accounts/{account_id}/clickwraps/{clickwrap_id}'
update_url = f'https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/v1/accounts/{account_id}/clickwraps/{clickwrap_id}' #/versions/{"V1.0"}

response = requests.post(update_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(clickwrap_request_body))
print("response.status_code post", response.status_code) ## i get 500
print(response.text) ## i get {"Message":"An error has occurred."}

response = requests.get(clickwrap_url, headers=headers)
print("response.status_code post", response.status_code) ## i get 401
print(response.text) ## i get Failed to fetch Clickwrap details.
```

edit 2 added code @InbarGazit

```
if code: # If authorization code, exchange for access token
  token token_url = 'account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token' 
  token_params = { 'code': code, 
  'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 
  'client_id': client_id, 
  'client_secret': client_secret, 
  'redirect_uri': redirect_uri } 

  response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_params)

   if response.status_code ==200:
      response_data = json.loads(response.text)
      access_token = response_data.get('access_token')
   else: 
      print(error exchanging for token)
```

below are images to better understand->

[sample error output if token expired, this never actually happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5EyT.png)

[this what i keep getting even after i have valid access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW2z7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Clickwraps, or Elastic templates are using a different API called the [Click API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/). The URLs you have there for the [DocuSign eSignature REST API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/)

Having said that, the URL you need would look like this:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/v1/accounts/{{accountId}}/clickwraps/{{clickwrapId}}/
```

Comment: im so sorry i just updated the post with new info. I am getting error 500 and 401 Im guessing thats related but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: cc.  @inbarGazit

Comment: i have OAuth token but i still keep getting error 401 and im pretty sure its not because it expired. theres a deeper issue but not sure how to proceed. @InbarGazit sorry i keep asking questions, i'd like to be done with this as quickly as possible. is there a way to quickly get in touch with someone that can help maybe over zoom or whatever means.

Comment: How did you obtain your auth token?

Comment: i get consent code in the url of a redirection webpage after I sign in to docusign while submitting my form with input fields. 
if code: 
        # If authorization code, exchange for access token
        token_url = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token'
        token_params = {
            'code': code,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'redirect_uri': redirect_uri
        }
        print(f"token_params")
       response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_params)

Comment: please look at edit 2 for the code. i get consent code in the url of a redirection webpage after I sign in to docusign while submitting my form. this authorization code is sent to aws lambda through gateway and exchanged for access token

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to make sure the authorization url to get the authorization token is correct lol. I hate computers.

```
auth_url = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth'
        auth_params = {
            'response_type': 'code',
            'client_id': client_id,
            'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
            'scope': 'click.manage' <- this was set to signature in accordance with e signature api that i was using before
        }
```

Comment: Glad you got it working